# Can a nonnegative linear functional on $L^\infty(R)$ be determined by its values on the set of bounded continuous function

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm given a problem by my professor：

$\hat{\mathbb{E}}$ is a sublinear expectation(Don't be afraid of this word,it's not related to this question) on $C_b(R)$,then can it be extended to $L^{\infty}(R)$(which means bouned Borel measurable function here),and is the extension unique?

I have solve the first part of the question,and reduce the second part of the question to the following functional analysis question about which I have no idea:

> If $I_1,I_2$ is a nonnegative linear functional on $L^{\infty}(R)$(i.e. the set of bounded Borel measurable function),and they have same value on $C_b$(i.e. the set of bounded continuous function),are they the same functional?

Can anyone help me solve it or give some reference?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the extension is definitely not unique. The zero functional has infinitely many extensions, given by $0$ and any "banach limit" (wikipedia)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich:''Banach limit'' on Wikipedia is a functional defined on $l^{\infty}$ but the functional above is defined on $L^{\infty}(R)$.Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Rixinner linear functions will have many extensions in general; many of which are continuous assuming topologies exist. Often mild conditions will guarantee unique extensions (e.g. Cauchy's extension theorem, Daniell's theorem, Kolmogorov's theorem, etc).

Comment: @WilliamM.:Do you have any reference?

Comment: I know that Ash's book "Real Analysis and Probability" tackles the extension of positive linear forms defined on lattices (i.e. Daniell's theorem) and if I remember correctly, his other book "Topics in Stochastic processes" tackles the uniqueness of extending a measure knowing some of its projections (i.e. Kolmogorov's extension theorem). Cauchy's extension theorem simply states that a _continuous_ linear function defined on a subspace can be extended uniquely to the closure of the subespace (e.g. when you have dense subspace as in $L^\infty \cap L^p$ inside $L^p$).

Comment: the same argument works on $\Bbb R^d$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is negative.  That is, there are non-negative linear functionals $I_1$ and $I_2$ that  coincide on $C_b(R)$, but $I_1\neq I_2$.

In order to exhibit a counter example,
observing that $C_b(R)$ is a proper, closed subspace of $L^\infty(R)$, one may use Hahn-Banach to produce a nonzero continuous linear functional $f$ on $L^\infty(R)$ which vanishes on $C_b(R)$.

One may then use the Hahn decomposition theorem to write $f=I_1-I_2$, where $I_1$ and $I_2$ are both non-negative linear functionals on $L^\infty(R)$.

Then clearly $I_1$ and $I_2$ coincide on $C_b(R)$, but $I_1\neq I_2$.